# How to store tokens in react native?

Tags: react-native

I used to develop in android previously and i used to used SharePreference for storing user tokens. Is there anything such available in react native for both ios and android?

Comment: What about https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-shared-preferences ?

Comment: for all other developer who looking for more weekly download and cover all platform like android, windows, Macos, Ios  https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-async-storage/async-storage

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You might want to use [AsyncStorage](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html)

Since `AsyncStorage` is deprecated now. You can use https://github.com/react-native-community/async-storage

**Edit:**

For everyone who has pointed out that AsyncStorage is not secure please refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39028755/save-sensitive-data-in-react-native).

Comment: This is not secure, please don't use it to store tokens or other sensitive data.

Comment: This also seems to have issues on certain Android devices between react-native versions 0.54 & 0.57 (See https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/18372)

Comment: This answer is not complete without stating that it's not secure. Tokens, which have been specifically asked for, are usually associated with vulnerable data. For secure storage, use https://github.com/oblador/react-native-keychain.

Comment: it is secure to save data in asyncStorage please refer to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39028755/save-sensitive-data-in-react-native

Comment: Just want to point out, asyncstorage is safe as long as the attacker doesn't have physical access to the device as well as the passcode or a trusted computer. If that's the case, the attacker can simply consume the tokens from the device anyhow. That being said, encryption couldn't hurt.

Comment: The official React Native site says: "DON'T USE ASYNC STORAGE FOR... Token storage". Please, check here: https://reactnative.dev/docs/security#async-storage

Answer (score 51):

If you're using `create-react-native-app` or `expo`, you can use `Expo.SecureStore` to store your token.

```js
    import {SecureStore} from 'expo';
    
    await SecureStore.setItemAsync('secure_token','sahdkfjaskdflas$%^&');
    const token = await SecureStore.getItemAsync('secure_token');
    console.log(token); // output: sahdkfjaskdflas$%^&
```

Details: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/securestore

Update in Dec 2020:

The SecureStore module is now become `expo-secure-store`

```js
    import * as SecureStore from 'expo-secure-store';
    
    await SecureStore.setItemAsync('secure_token','sahdkfjaskdflas$%^&');
    const token = await SecureStore.getItemAsync('secure_token');
    console.log(token); // output: sahdkfjaskdflas$%^&
```

Comment: It worked, but I needed to install it like this "expo install expo-secure-store" and import it like this "import * as SecureStore from 'expo-secure-store'"

Comment: SecureStore worked great for iOS and Android, but came up short for web in expo.io: "SecureStore.setItemAsync is not available on web"

Comment: Actually you can use it also in for bare React Native projects, but the installation is more involved: https://github.com/expo/expo/tree/master/packages/expo-secure-store#installation-in-bare-react-native-projects

Comment: How is using `Expo.SecureStore` completely safe? It seems like if an app is the target of an XSS  attack or has a vulnerable dependency, malicious code could still call `SecureStore` to let's say get the user's access token and send it to a remote server. Am I missing something in that scenario?

Answer (score 20):

Here are some ways to store persistent data in React Native:

- [async-storage](https://github.com/react-native-community/async-storage) stores unencrypted, key-value data. Do not use Async Storage for storing Token, Secrets and other confidential data. Do use Async Storage for persisting Redux state, GraphQL state and storing global app-wide variables.
- [react-native-keychain](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-keychain) stores username/password combination in the secure storage in string format. Use JSON.stringify/JSON.parse when you store/access it.
- [react-native-sensitive-info](https://github.com/mCodex/react-native-sensitive-info) - secure for iOS, but uses Android Shared Preferences for Android (which is not secure by default). There is however a [fork](https://github.com/mCodex/react-native-sensitive-info/tree/keystore)) that uses Android Keystore.
- [redux-persist-sensitive-storage](https://github.com/CodingZeal/redux-persist-sensitive-storage) - wraps react-native-sensitive-info

More info about [React Native Storage & Security](https://reactnative.dev/docs/security)

Comment: Excellent summary.

Answer (score 16):

As an addition to the other answer, you might want to consider encrypting the token on the user device when storing it.

So in addition to storing it via AsyncStorage you might want to use something like: [react-native-keychain](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-keychain) to encrypt it on the device.

Answer (score 13):

use expo-secure-store

```js
// to install it 'expo install expo-secure-store'

import * as SecureStore from 'expo-secure-store';

const setToken = (token) => {
    return SecureStore.setItemAsync('secure_token', token);
};

const getToken = () => {
    return SecureStore.getItemAsync('secure_token');
};

setToken('#your_secret_token');
getToken().then(token => console.log(token)); // output '#your_secret_token'
```

Comment: This works well, but when I'm using the web to debug I get this error -> The method or property SecureStore.setItemAsync is not available on web, are you sure you've linked all the native dependencies properly?

Comment: Platform Compatibility not include `web`

Answer (score 1):

According to the [React Native docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/security#secure-storage):

> React Native does not come bundled with any way of storing sensitive data. However, there are pre-existing solutions for Android and iOS platforms.

But here are some alternatives using iOS - Keychain Services & Android - Secure Shared Preferences. See the following [docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/security#ios---keychain-services)

Also, here are a few options out of the box:

- [expo-secure-store](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/securestore/)
- [react-native-encrypted-storage](https://github.com/emeraldsanto/react-native-encrypted-storage)
- [react-native-keychain](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-keychain)

Answer (score -1):

Try this example from React Native Expo

Note: This example is for unencrypted usage so if you want secure storage so visit this page for nore information https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/securestore

Reference:
Unencrypted
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/auth-flow.html#set-up-our-navigators
Encrypted
https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/securestore

```js
class SignInScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Please sign in',
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Button title="Sign in!" onPress={this._signInAsync} />
      </View>
    );
  }

  _signInAsync = async () => {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('userToken', 'abc');
    this.props.navigation.navigate('App');
  };
}

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Welcome to the app!',
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Button title="Show me more of the app" onPress={this._showMoreApp} />
        <Button title="Actually, sign me out :)" onPress={this._signOutAsync} />
      </View>
    );
  }

  _showMoreApp = () => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Other');
  };

  _signOutAsync = async () => {
    await AsyncStorage.clear();
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Auth');
  };
}

// More code like OtherScreen omitted for brevity
```