# Passing params to nested React Navigation states

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

My structure is as follows:

- Switch navigator

  - LoginScreen
  - Drawer navigator

    - Stack navigator

      - ListTasksScreen
    - Stack navigator

      - ListDirectivesScreen

The app starts at the login screen. When logging in succeeds, I `this.props.navigate()` to `ListTasksScreen` and pass credentials to it.

However when the user now changes the screen by opening the drawer and pressing an item, parameters are lost. Without the credentials, I can't query an API.

Code:

```
export const app = createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    login: {screen: LoginScreen}, 
    main: {screen: MainScreen},
  },
  {initialRouteName: "login"}
)

export class LoginScreen extends React.Component {
  performLogin() {
    this.props.navigation.navigate(
      "listTasks",
      {api: this.api, userId: response.id}
    )
  }
}

export const MainScreen = createDrawerNavigator({
  listTasksStack: {screen: createStackNavigator({listTasks: ListTasksScreen})},
  listDirectivesStack: {screen: createStackNavigator({listDirectives: ListDirectivesScreen})},
  logout: {screen: LogoutScreen},
})

export class ListTasksScreen extends React.Component {
  doSomething() {
    this.props.navigation.getParam("api") // <-- Not available!
  }
}

export class ListDirectivesScreen extends React.Component {}
export class LogoutScreen extends React.Component {}
```

Is there a way to pass parameters down to children, or access parent parameters? Or are there other approaches?

Comment: Please post relevant code snippets of your components.

Comment: One way of doing this would be to keep a state say, `isLoggedIn`whose default value is `false` and switches to `true` once a user logged in. You can then keep the api credentials in a variable than can be accessed only if `isLoggedIn` is true.

Comment: @AndrewL Source added. Where do I keep that state? I want to store an API token and user ID which I need in several screens for querying an API.

Comment: My opinion based on my experience - I found React Navigation to be absolutely disastrous and realized how can something so simple be so hard. I ended up using Wix's React-native-navigation (https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation). I love it and I have it in every single RN project. If you're fairly new to React-Navigation, my recommendation would be to switch soon.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you can not access your credential after you move away from `ListTasksScreen` is because your credential is a prop in the `ListTasksScreen` component.

You probably want something else to store user credential in your app, and let `react-navigation` just handle navigation.

An easy way to get started is to use `AsyncStorage`:

```
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
// ...

class LogInScreen extends React.Component {
   handleLogIn = () {
      this.logIn(token => {
        AsyncStorage.setItem('MyToken', token);
      });
    }
}
```

Then in your other screen you can retrieve your token:

```
getData = () => {
  AsyncStorage.getItem('MyToken').then(token => {
    const headers = { Authentication: `Bearer ${token}` };
    fetch('my-backend.com/api/data', { method: 'GET', headers }).then(
      // ...
    )
  });
}
```

This is a safe way to store sensitive information [read more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39028755/save-sensitive-data-in-react-native).

However you can also use this [react-native-keychain](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-keychain) to store in your user credentials.