# What is the proper way to store sensitive data in react native app?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

the most secure way to save sensitive data such as  token or payment information .

should I store them in the android AsyncStorage, in the redux-store or shared preferences?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Save sensitive data in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39028755/save-sensitive-data-in-react-native)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The libraries**

Now multiples libraries allow you to store sensitive in React Native code:

- **[expo-secure-store](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/securestore/)**
- **[react-native-keychain](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-keychain)**
- **[react-native-encrypted-storage](https://github.com/emeraldsanto/react-native-encrypted-storage)**

Note: On the native side, these libraries can use:

- **[Keychain](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/keychain_services) for iOS**
- **[Android Keystore](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore) for Android**
- **[Encrypted Shared Preferences](https://developer.android.com/topic/security/data) for Android**

Answer (score -1):

When it comes to storing sensitive data in a React Native app, it's important to use a secure storage solution that encrypts the data at rest, so that it can't be easily accessed by unauthorized parties. Some options for secure storage in a React Native app include:

**Keychain**: The Keychain is an iOS-only solution that stores the data in an encrypted format on the device's secure enclave. It is a built-in iOS feature and the most secure way to store sensitive data.

**Encryption libraries**: You can use encryption libraries such as react-native-sensitive-info or react-native-keychain to encrypt the data yourself before storing it. These libraries provide an API for encrypting and decrypting data, which you can use to protect sensitive data in your app.

**Secure storage libraries**: There are also libraries specifically designed for secure storage in React Native apps such as react-native-secure-storage which will take care of encryption and storage together.